# C# Jagged Array check if value exists/true

Tags: c#, jagged-arrays

This is my code , i am using 2 dimension array .

```
top = 0;
if(rowcol[i-1][j]){ top = rowcol[i-1][j] }
```

But it shows this error :

Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'

Full code :

```
 string[] fileData = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\apr13mpsip\Desktop\OneOrganizer\OneOrganizer\WordPuzzle\testing.txt");

        string[] lineValues;

        int row = 0;
        int col;

        string[][] rowcol = new string[fileData.Length][];

        foreach (string line in fileData)
        {
            lineValues = line.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None);


            rowcol[row] = new string[lineValues.Length];

            col = 0;

            foreach (string value in lineValues)
            {
                rowcol[row][col] = value;
                col++;
            }
            row++;

        }


        for (int i = 0; i < rowcol.GetLength(0) ; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < rowcol[i].GetLength(0) ; j++)
            {


                int iadd =  i+1 <rowcol.GetLength(0) ? i + 1: 0;
                int iminus =   i-1> 0  ? i - 1 : 0;
                int jadd =  j+1 <rowcol.GetLength(0) ? j + 1 : 0;
                int jminus = j-1 > 0 ? j - 1 : 0;
                var self = rowcol[i][j]; // current value

                top = 0;
if(rowcol[iminus][j]){ top = rowcol[iminus][j] } // ERROR HERE
}
}
```

i am actually reading from a textfile and creating something out of it by creating rows and cols 10x10 in a jagged array. so i could find their value by rowcol[][] .

Answer (score 3):

because

```
if(rowcol[i-1][j])
```

will return **string** as per your definition

```
string[][] rowcol
```

and **if statement needs bool**. you need to check it against something like

```
if(rowcol[i-1][j] == "stringtotest")
```

Answer (score 2):

Only boolean expression can be used as `if` condition, for example:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rowcol[i-1][j]))
```

Comment: how do i return a null if it is empty

Comment: @user2376998, not sure if I understood you question correctly. `string.IsNullOrEmpty` returns `true` if string in test is either null or empty, and `false` otherwise. So if you use the condition above as is, `top` will be assigned only when `rowcol[i-1][j]` is neither null nor empty. Is this what you are looking for?